# Sql management Studio 2014 crashed + backup databases before reinstall

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-backups

I have installed sql server 2014 standard edition on windows server 2012R2, it was working fine. but after few days i try to open management studio but it says ***cannot find one or more components try reinstalling the application***. i have seen many solution for recovery and reinstalling but my first concern is data backup. as its a live system i dont want to lose any data. can any one tell so surely that how i can backup data and recover management studio. are there any files which need to be copied and can be replaced after reinstalling. i will be thankful if some one can give sure answer. Again remember its a live system i cannot lose any data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that SQL services are still online, you can take backup using sqlcmd and try to repair the management studio.

example.

SqlCmd -E -S Server_Name –Q “BACKUP DATABASE [Name_of_Database] TO DISK=’X:PathToBackupLocation[Name_of_Database].bak'”